# Why does `for x in list[None:None]:` work?

Tags: python, slice

I have a script that attempts to read the begin and end point for a subset via a binary search, these values are then used to create a slice for further processing.

I noticed that when these variables did not get set (the search returned None) the code would still run and in the end I noticed that a slice spanning from None to None works as if examining the entire list (see example below).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for x in list[None:None]:
  print x
```

Does anyone know why the choice was made to see the `list[None:None]` simply as `list[:]`, at least that's what I think that happens (correct me if I'm wrong). I personally would think that throwing a TypeError would be desirable in such a case.

Comment: I suspect the choice was actually made to see `list[:]` as `list[None:None]`.

Comment: Probably for exactly your use case. If you have a `start` and `end` point that you're setting from somewhere else, if `list[None:None]` didn't work then you'd have no chance of recovery. This way, you can test before hand `if not any(x is None for x in [start,end]):`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `None` is the *default* for slice positions. You can use either `None` or omit the value altogether, at which point `None` is passed in for you.

`None` is the default because you can use a negative stride, at which point what the default start and end positions are *changed*. Compare `list[0:len(list):-1]` to `list[None:None:-1]`, for example.

Python uses `None` for 'value not specified' throughout the standard library; this is no exception.

Note that if your class implements the [`object.__getitem__` hook](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), you'll get passed a `slice()` object with the start, end and stride attributes set to `None` as well:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         print key
... 
>>> Foo()[:]
slice(None, None, None)
```

Since `Foo()` doesn't even implement a `__len__` having the defaults use `None` is entirely logical here.

Comment: I will have to have my binary search functions return something other than None then. Thank you for the elaboration.

Comment: @BasJansen You can either test the results for `None:None` or throw an exception instead. Both is quite Pythonic. Using special "magic" values usually isn't a good choice.

Comment: @BasJansen The search function should return values relevant to the search, not based on how you will use them beyond the search (e.g. don't return `(0, 0)` just so you will get an empty slice with `[0:0]`, if zeroes aren't logical search results). The better solution is to check for `None`s before you attempt the slice.

Answer (score 3):

I also think that `list[None:None]` is interpreted as `list[:]`. This is handy behavior because you can do something like this:

```
return list[some_params.get('start'):some_params.get('end')]
```

If the list slicing wouldn't work with `None`, you would have to check if `start` and `end` were `None` yourself:

```
if some_params.get('start') and some_params.get('end'):
    return list[some_params.get('start'):some_params.get('end')]
elif some_params.get('start'):
    return list[some_params.get('start'):]
elif end:
    return list[:some_params.get('end')]
else:
    return list[:]
```

Fortunately this is not the case in Python :).

Comment: I was expecting that a slice between two identical variables would be 0 but as is clear from my question and it's subsequent answers it is taken as 'default' or 'unspecified'.

Comment: Could be golfed to `return list[some_params.get('start'):some_params.get('end')]`.

Answer (score 1):

`None` is the usual representation for "parameter not given", so you can communicate the fact to a function. You will often see functions or methods declared like this

```
def f(p=None):
    if f is None:
        f = some_default_value()
```

I guess this makes the choice clear: Be using `None` you can tell the slicer to use its default values.